# Extension Methods - How to return the correct type in inheritance?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I'm trying to create a generic methods from my Repository classes. The idea is a method that do something and return the instance of the class who called it.

```
public class BaseRepository { }

public class FooRepository : BaseRepository { }

public class BarRepository : BaseRepository { }

public static class ExtensionRepository
{
    public static BaseRepository AddParameter(this BaseRepository self, string parameterValue)
    {
        //...
        return self;
    }
}

// Calling the test:
FooRepository fooRepository = new FooRepository();
BaseRepository fooWrongInstance = fooRepository.AddParameter("foo");

BarRepository barRepository = new BarRepository();
BaseRepository barWrongInstance = barRepository.AddParameter("bar");
```

Well, this way I can get BaseRepository instance. But I need to get FooRepository and BarRepository instances, who called this method. Any idea? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Do you realize that a `class` type variable is just a _reference_ to the object? What's the purpose of returning _the same_ reference back to the caller of the method? He already has that reference. There may be a valid reason (which is why I ask). Addition: In your usage example above, the `=` sign simply assigns _the same_ reference to the new variable. It's not a "wrong instance". The method doesn't create new instances; it's the same instance.

Comment: The purpose of returning the same reference, Jeppe, is to realize a lot of method calls on a row. "Wrong instance" was a way to say that I want the children instances like returning, but not the base class, you know?

Comment: Now I understand. The correct term is "wrong (unwanted) compile-time type" or "type of the variable", I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using generics

```
public static class ExtensionRepository
{
    public static T AddParameter<T>(this T self, string parameterValue) where T:BaseRepository 
    {
        //...
        return self;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but we can improve this by using `where T : BaseRepository`

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I've already thought this solution, but I want to create an elegant code. Something like: "fooRepository.AddParameter("value")" instead "fooRepository.AddParameter<FooRepository>("value")", you know?

Comment: @Kiwanax, You don't need to specify the type in `<>` , it will be infered by compiler. Your code will look like `fooRepository.AddParameter("value")`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to return `self` in the first place? As far as I can see (don't know what's inside your method body) you don't assign a new object to `self`. So it's the same instance you're returning as the caller already has.

Maybe you could make it return `void`:

```
public static void AddParameter(this BaseRepository self, string parameterValue)
{
    //...
}
```

Usage:

```
FooRepository fooRepository = new FooRepository();
fooRepository.AddParameter("foo");
// fooRepository is still fooRepository after the call


BarRepository barRepository = new BarRepository();
barRepository.AddParameter("bar");
// barRepository is still barRepository after the call
```

Comment: The purpose of returning the same instance is to call a lot of methods in a row, you know? Like: "fooRepository.AddParameter("").AddSomeStuff("", "").AddAnotherStuff("").List();". Something like this.

Comment: @Kiwanax Alright, then you could use the solution from the other answer.

Comment: Yeah, @Jeppe, the another solution solved my problem. Thank you for your answers!